# How can I run Pickles-Features command from my method

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core, picklesdoc

I am making WinForm application for .Net Core project to generate test documentation.

I want to 1) execute dotnet test 2) generate pickles documentantion json file from xml and feature files 3) create custom xml from that file.

I am able to execute tests ang generate TestResults.xml,
i.e. `# dotnet test --logger:xunit -r ../TestResults/`

```
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/C cd {solution_directory};" +
            "dotnet test --logger:xunit -r ../TestResults/;"
```

Now I try to run Pickles-Features for generated xml and feature files of Project.
But it's not available with the same technique

> Pickle-Feature : The term 'Pickle-Feature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I installed it via Nuget but this didn't work.

How can I use it in my form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run it from default nuget packages installation directory.

```
var userDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
var pickles = userDirectory + "\\.nuget\\packages\\pickles.commandline\\2.20.1\\tools\\pickles.exe";
var arguments = $" -f={featuresDirectory}" +
            $" -o={reportsOutputDirectory}" +
            $" --link-results-file={reportsOutputDirectory}/TestResults.xml" +
            " --test-results-format=xunit2" +
            " --documentation-format=json";
```